# How can I get rid of this nested loop with sapply?

Tags: r

I am somewhat new to R, and have written the following nested loop:

```
for (col in date2) {
    for (row in 1:nrow(file2)) {
      file2[row, col] <- as.character(parse_date_time(file2[row, col], c("Ymd", "mdY", "mdy", "ymd", 
                                                                         "mdy_HM", "mdy_H", "mdy_HMS", 
                                                                         "ymd_HM", "ymd_H", "ymd_HMS")))
    }
  }
```

I noticed that the code runs much, much slower now, likely since R is not optimized for running nested loops quickly. Is there a way I can refactor this using `sapply`? I have attempted to do so but so far have had no luck in getting it to run as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have row and column index, `cbind` it and extract the elements of 'file2'

```
library(lubridate)
ij <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(file2)), seq_along(date2))    
parse_date_time(file2[ij], fmtVec)
```

---

If the intention is to apply on multiple columns

```
library(dplyr)
file2 %>%
      mutate_at(vars(date2), parse_date_time, select_formats = fmtVec)
```

---

Or using `lapply` from `base R`

```
file2[date2] <- lapply(file2[date2], parse_date_time, select_formats = fmtVec)
```

#### data

```
fmtVec <- c("Ymd", "mdY", "mdy", "ymd",  "mdy_HM", "mdy_H", "mdy_HMS", 
                            "ymd_HM", "ymd_H", "ymd_HMS")
```